# What does status Indexed '-' mean in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I am quite new to Google Webmaster Tools (SEO in general). I recently uploaded an XML sitemap to Google via Google Webmaster Tools. I had to resubmit it after an error was reported in the XML. Now I see the following. Not sure what this status means? Has it been crawled? Just want to know so I can check the ranking in search.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphen in the "Indexed" column is simply indicating that it's not yet able to report on how many URLs from your XML sitemap are currently indexed. The processed date is only *today*, so give it some more time.

Check Google Index > Index Status to check the total number of URLs indexed (irrespective of your sitemap).

Also perform a `site:example.com` search in Google to see what results are returned for your site.